# how to convert c string to xml using standard c++?

Tags: c++, xml, string

I would like to know is there any way to generate xml schema from a c string by using stander c++? In my current application there is a server which sends comma separated string by a socket. That is cumbersome to parse date. I would like to extend this to convert this string into a standard XML format. So that I could easily parse data from client side.

c string:-
Temperature,low:20,high:30,current:24

xml:-

```
<temperature>
  <low>20</low>
  <high>30</high>
  <current>24</current>
</temperature>
```

Please provide some link or example to study more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you have two separate steps:

1. Parse the String and get the information you want out of it
2. Write the XML

For Step 1. I would suggest using some regular expression library, e.g. [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html).

As soon as you have the information parsed, you can simply write the XML into a string using standard streams like

```
std::stringstream s;
s << "<temperature><low>" << low << "</low><high>" << high << "</high>";
s << "<current>" << current << "</current>";
s << "</temperature>";
```

and use the resulting string with `s.str()`.

Answer (score 1):

C++ doesn't have a XML parser as part of the standard library.  To do this you need a 3rd party library. [MSXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb190600) and [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) are two that I have used. While Xerces is a little more cumbersome to set up I have to say it is much nicer of the two.

Comment: [PugiXml](http://pugixml.org/) is another library: very smart, free and fast, providing DOM and a XPath implementation.

Comment: There are lots of XML implementations but I only mentioned the two I have actually used.